# Is there a good way to shift part of the dataframe until a match is achieved?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dplyr

I need to compare the values of two tables with the same columns, but the data for them was taken from two different databases. Here is a chunk of a table that was sent to me:
[information about tasks in a mobile app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02NJd.png)

I have my own table but with some differences:
[information from another database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7v8V.png)

You can see that in my table there is a row with 22 task_id while other table doesn't has its id, and to compare this two tables firstly I need to make the rows have the same id values. For example, if my table in a row has 22 task_id while row from other table has 23 task_id and I know that 23 task_id is exactly below in my table I want to shift values of other table below until the task_id in the row match

I've already found ids which are exactly not in other table and tried to solve this problem using for() and while() but I didn't get any good results.

Comment: Your question is missing a [mre] (images are not accepted and make sure to provide a **small** dummy example), also provide the matching expected output. You can identify the missing row with `~df2['our_name'].isin(df1['task_name'])`

Comment: Also make sure to pick **one language**, [tag:pandas] OR [tag:R] as well as your existing attempt.